# Continuous input from eventTrigger OnPointerDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Just like `Input.GetKey()` for keyboard is there any way to take continuous input from UI button **event trigger** `OnPointerDown` ?  Because for movement controls with animation its giving very weird output? I have to click it again and again which I don't want to!

And if answer is **manually tracking** then how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` functions then use a simple boolean variable to keep the states. You can then check of the press in the Update function.

```
public class YourCode : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool pointerDown = false;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pointerDown = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pointerDown = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (pointerDown)
        {
            //Your Code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to attach this script to all Touch buttons one by one which have `Eventtrigger` component attached to it and using`OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` functions ?

Comment: And does every script should be having **specific** code in `Update()` according to specific button which is using `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp`  ?  @Programmer

Comment: It should be attached to each UI Button. So attach the YourCode  script above to each UI Button. Put the code you want to run inside the `if (pointerDown)` code. It will be called in every frame until released.

Comment: If you have a main script you want to integrate this with, you can add an [event](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events) to it. Subscribe to the event from the main script then call the event in the `if (pointerDown)`.

Comment: I understood...but attaching is easier..THNX

Answer (score -1):

no.

You have to manually track the events. Using `EventTrigger` is as good as it gets.

Comment: Manually track the events ?

Comment: how to do that @Doug ?

Comment: plz give some info